# Select nth dataset from library using sas proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a library holding monthly data and I would like to select last three months data.
For the most recent data, i used the below code.
The desired result is to create &data, &data1, &data2, for three months data.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT MEMNAME INTO: DATA FROM DICTIONARY.TABLES
WHERE UPCASE(MEMNAME) = 'LIBNAME'
AND UPCASE(MEMNAME) LIKE 'DATA20%'
AND LENGTH(MEMNAME)=10 AND NOBS > 1
ORDER BY MEMNAME DESCENDING;
QUIT;
```

I tried adding where monotonic() = 2 before order by statement but it gave me the 2nd data by ascending instead.
How can I extract it in a descending way.

Comment: What is the naming convention? Data202008 for Aug 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can use this as a template

```
data data202001; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202002; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202003; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202004; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202005; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202006; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202007; set sashelp.class; run;
data data202008; set sashelp.class; run;

proc sql outobs=3 noprint;
   select memname into :data1 -
   from dictionary.tables
   where libname = "WORK" 
      and upcase(memname) like "DATA%"
      and nobs > 1
   order by memname desc;
quit;

%put &data1. &data2. &data3.;
```

Prints:

DATA1=DATA202008 DATA2=DATA202007 DATA3=DATA202006

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Proc SQL` option `OUTOBS=` to restrict output to the first N rows of a result set.

Example:

```
PROC SQL;
reset noprint outobs=3;

SELECT MEMNAME INTO: DATA separated by ' '
FROM DICTIONARY.TABLES
WHERE LIBNAME = 'SASHELP'
AND MEMNAME LIKE 'C%'
AND NOBS > 1
ORDER BY MEMNAME DESCENDING
;
QUIT;

%put &=DATA;
```

Log

```
DATA=CP951 COUNTSERIES COMET
```